# What allows SQL Server to trade an object name for a string passed to a system procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax, parameter, database-internals

What causes it to be legal to pass an object name to the system stored procedure `sp_helptext`?

What mechanism converts the object name to a string?

e.g.

```
-- works
sp_helptext myproc
sp_helptext [myproc]
sp_helptext [dbo.myproc]
-- and behaves the same as a string
sp_helptext 'myproc'
sp_helptext 'dbo.myproc'

-- does not work
sp_helptext dbo.myproc -- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 incorrect syntax near '.'
-- an additional case that does not work.
sp_helptext [dbo].[myproc] -- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 incorrect syntax
```

It seems odd that I'm not *required* to single quote valid proc names, unless it has a `.` separating schema name and procedure name. I'm looking for an explanation of how it gets auto converted from a quoted name to a string literal to be passed as the value of the parameter.

I don't have a specific issue to resolve; I am simply inquisitive about things that aren't documented.

Comment: Contributions in comments have been **[moved to this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49869/discussion-on-question-by-jjs-what-allows-sql-server-to-trade-an-object-name-for)**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first argument to the system stored procedure [`sp_helptext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) is:

> `[`**`@objname`**`= ] 'name'`
>   Is the qualified or nonqualified name of a user-defined, schema-scoped object. Quotation marks are required only if a qualified object is specified. If a fully qualified name, including a database name, is provided, the database name must be the name of the current database. The object must be in the current database. name is **`nvarchar(776)`**, with no default.

In addition, the documentation for Delimited Identifiers (Database Engine) states:

> **[Using Identifiers As Parameters in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx#Anchor_2)**
>   Many system stored procedures, functions, and DBCC statements take object names as parameters. Some of these parameters accept multipart object names, while others accept only single-part names. Whether a single-part or multipart name is expected determines how a parameter is parsed and used internally by SQL Server.
>
> **Single-part Parameter Names**
>   If the parameter is a single-part identifier, the name can be specified in the following ways:
>
> - Without quotation marks or delimiters
> - Enclosed in single quotation marks
> - Enclosed in double quotation marks
> - Enclosed in brackets
>
> **Multipart Parameter Names**
>   Multipart names are qualified names that include the database or schema name and also the object name. When a multipart name is used as a parameter, SQL Server requires that the complete string that makes up the multipart name be enclosed in a set of single quotation marks.

---

The first argument to `sp_helptext` accepts both single-part (nonqualified) and multipart (qualified) object names.

If the T-SQL parser interprets the item after `sp_helptext` as a **single-part name** (in accordance with the four bullet points above), the resulting name is passed as the (string type) argument value expected by the procedure.

When the parser sees it as a **multipart name**, the text is required to be surrounded with single quotation marks as stated.

The key feature of a multipart name is a `.` separator (outside any delimiters).

These examples from the question are successfully interpreted as single-part names:

```
myproc       - single-part (without quotation marks or delimiters - bullet #1)
[myproc]     - single-part (in brackets - bullet #4)
'myproc'     - single-part (in single quotation marks - bullet #2)
'dbo.myproc' - multipart with the required single quotation marks
[dbo.myproc] - single-part (in brackets - bullet #4)
```

The last two examples from the question are both parsed as multipart parameter names (due to the exposed `.` separator). They produce an error because they lack the required enclosing single quotation marks:

```
dbo.myproc     - multipart without the required single quotation marks
[dbo].[myproc] - multipart without the required single quotation marks
```

This extra example using double quotation marks is successful:

```
"dbo.myproc" - single-part (in double quotation marks - bullet point #3)
```

Note that it is successfully interpreted (for the procedure parameter value) as being a valid **single-part** name, but the procedure code is able to interpret the (multipart) string it receives flexibly (using [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) and [`OBJECTID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx)).

As a final point of interest, note that using double quotation marks here does not depend on the setting of [`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx).