# Is the function PARSENAME() the opposite of QUOTENAME()

Tags: sql-server, functions, string-manipulation

In the question [Is there any (hidden) built-in function on MS-SQL to unquote object names?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/195923/15356) the author was seeking advice on if there was an internal function to "UNQUOTE" a quoted string. The author [McNets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/110455/mcnets) had noticed, that some internal functions could handle quoted (e.g. `[MyTable]`) and unquoted (e.g. `MyTable`) parameter values passed on (e.g. `OBJECT_ID()`).

In the answer ([1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195940/15356)) given by [David Browne - Microsoft](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft) the quote was made that:

> ...the inverse of QUOTENAME is PARSENAME, which has the additional ability to navigate multi-part names.

I disagreed with this part of the answer with the following comment:

> I do agree that you can modify an argument passed to `PARSENAME()` to display the parts of a multi-part identifier be it the `SERVER`, `DATABASE`, `SCHEMA` or `OBJECT` part. But IMHO stating that `PARSENAME` is the opposite of `QUOTENAME` is a bit far-fetched.

My question now is:

**Is the function `PARSENAME()` the opposite of `QUOTENAME()`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comment by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) which reads:

> ...can you find a string `x` that `parsename(quotename(x),1)` will be different than `x`? If not, that falls into the definition of "inverse function" ;)  ...

... I created a simple statement to have a look at the different values returned by these functions. The code is as follows:

### Code

```
DECLARE 
-- Text that I will be converting using QUOTENAME()
@Text2Quote_1 AS NVARCHAR(20),
@Text2Quote_2 AS NVARCHAR(20),
@Text2Quote_3 AS NVARCHAR(20),
@Text2Quote_4 AS NVARCHAR(20),
-- The characters used for "quotation"
@QuoteChar_1 AS NCHAR(1),
@QuoteChar_2 AS NCHAR(1),
@QuoteChar_3 AS NCHAR(1),
-- The Parsing option as defined in the original MS documnenation for PARSSENAME()
@ParseParam AS INT

SET @Text2Quote_1 = N'Test'
SET @Text2Quote_2 = N'[Test]'
SET @Text2Quote_3 = N'Test.dbo.test'
SET @Text2Quote_4 = N'[Test].[dbo].[test]'

SET @QuoteChar_1 = ''''
SET @QuoteChar_2 = '[' 
SET @QuoteChar_3 = '"' 

SET @ParseParam = 1 -- Parsing level : Object name
-- checking the results for ' single quotes
SELECT  @Text2Quote_1 AS OriginalText_1,
        @Text2Quote_2 AS OriginalText_2,
        @Text2Quote_3 AS OriginalText_3,
        @Text2Quote_4 AS OriginalText_4
SELECT  QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_1,@QuoteChar_1) AS QuotedText_1, 
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_2,@QuoteChar_1) AS QuotedText_2, 
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_3,@QuoteChar_1) AS QuotedText_3, 
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_4,@QuoteChar_1) AS QuotedText_4
select  PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_1,@QuoteChar_1),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_1, 
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_2,@QuoteChar_1),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_2,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_3,@QuoteChar_1),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_3,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_4,@QuoteChar_1),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_4
```

Basically, I set a string values, output that value, `QUOTENAME()` and output the value, then `PARSENAME()` the `QUOTENAME()`ed value and output it.

### Results

The results were quite interesting:

```
OriginalText_1           OriginalText_2           OriginalText_3           OriginalText_4          
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
Test                     [Test]                   Test.dbo.test            [Test].[dbo].[test]     

(1 row(s) affected)                                                                                

QuotedText_1             QuotedText_2             QuotedText_3             QuotedText_4            
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
'Test'                   '[Test]'                 'Test.dbo.test'          '[Test].[dbo].[test]'   

(1 row(s) affected)                                                                                

Parsed_QuotedText_1      Parsed_QuotedText_2      Parsed_QuotedText_3      Parsed_QuotedText_4     
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
'Test'                   NULL                     test'                    NULL                    

(1 row(s) affected)
```

When the base text `Test.dbo.test` (**OriginalText_3**) is passed on to the `QUOTENAME()` function it gets converted to: `'Test.dbo.test'` (**QuotedText_3**)

When the **QuotedText_3** string `'Test.dbo.test'` is passed on to the `PARSENAME()` function it is converted to: `test'` (**Parsed_QuotedText_3**)

### Conclusion

Seeing as I have proven [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)'s thesis wrong, I think it is safe to state that the function `PARSENAME()` is not the inverse of `QUOTENAME()`.

---

*Based on [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)'s [feedback](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196015/is-the-function-parsename-the-opposite-of-quotename#comment382257_196016) here the code for square brackets `[ ]` (add to original script)*

### Additional Code for square brackets `[ ]`

```
-- checking the results for [ brackets                                                                           
SELECT  @Text2Quote_1 AS OriginalText_1,                                                                         
        @Text2Quote_2 AS OriginalText_2,                                                                         
        @Text2Quote_3 AS OriginalText_3,                                                                         
        @Text2Quote_4 AS OriginalText_4                                                                          
SELECT  QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_1,@QuoteChar_2) AS QuotedText_1,                             
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_2,@QuoteChar_2) AS QuotedText_2,                             
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_3,@QuoteChar_2) AS QuotedText_3,                             
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_4,@QuoteChar_2) AS QuotedText_4                              
select  PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_1,@QuoteChar_2),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_1,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_2,@QuoteChar_2),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_2,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_3,@QuoteChar_2),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_3,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_4,@QuoteChar_2),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_4
```

### Output for square brackets `[ ]`

```
OriginalText_1           OriginalText_2           OriginalText_3           OriginalText_4
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
Test                     [Test]                   Test.dbo.test            [Test].[dbo].[test]

(1 row(s) affected)

QuotedText_1             QuotedText_2             QuotedText_3             QuotedText_4
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
[Test]                   [[Test]]]                [Test.dbo.test]          [[Test]].[dbo]].[test]]]

(1 row(s) affected)

Parsed_QuotedText_1      Parsed_QuotedText_2      Parsed_QuotedText_3      Parsed_QuotedText_4
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
Test                     [Test]                   Test.dbo.test            [Test].[dbo].[test]

(1 row(s) affected)
```

*and to complete things the code for the double quotes*

### Additional code for double quotes `"`

```
-- checking the results for [ brackets                                                                           
SELECT  @Text2Quote_1 AS OriginalText_1,                                                                         
        @Text2Quote_2 AS OriginalText_2,                                                                         
        @Text2Quote_3 AS OriginalText_3,                                                                         
        @Text2Quote_4 AS OriginalText_4                                                                          
SELECT  QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_1,@QuoteChar_3) AS QuotedText_1,                             
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_2,@QuoteChar_3) AS QuotedText_2,                             
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_3,@QuoteChar_3) AS QuotedText_3,                             
        QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_4,@QuoteChar_3) AS QuotedText_4                              
select  PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_1,@QuoteChar_3),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_1,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_2,@QuoteChar_3),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_2,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_3,@QuoteChar_3),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_3,
        PARSENAME(QUOTENAME(@Text2Quote_4,@QuoteChar_3),@ParseParam) AS Parsed_QuotedText_4
```

### Output for double quotes `"`

```
OriginalText_1           OriginalText_2           OriginalText_3           OriginalText_4
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
Test                     [Test]                   Test.dbo.test            [Test].[dbo].[test]

(1 row(s) affected)

QuotedText_1             QuotedText_2             QuotedText_3             QuotedText_4
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
"Test"                   "[Test]"                 "Test.dbo.test"          "[Test].[dbo].[test]"

(1 row(s) affected)

Parsed_QuotedText_1      Parsed_QuotedText_2      Parsed_QuotedText_3      Parsed_QuotedText_4
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
Test                     [Test]                   Test.dbo.test            [Test].[dbo].[test]

(1 row(s) affected)
```

---

*Based on [ypercube™](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)'s [feedback](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196015/is-the-function-parsename-the-opposite-of-quotename/196016#comment382277_196016) and [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)'s new [feedback](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196015/is-the-function-parsename-the-opposite-of-quotename/196016#comment382263_196016) we have come to a mutual conclusion*

`PARSENAME()` is the inverse of `QUOTENAME()` if the following conditions are met:

**`PARSENAME(x,1)`<sup>`-1`</sup>`(QUOTENAME(x,q))` where `q={1,2}` and `x='{'any_string_value'}`**

---

### References:

- [PARSENAME (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) (Microsoft Docs)
- [QUOTENAME (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: All of your examples use `@QuoteChar_1` as the second argument to `QUOTENAME()`, why? This is *not* a valid character for a quoted identifier. `SELECT 'column', [column], "column" FROM (SELECT [column] = 1) x;` IMHO, the *spirit* of David's comment was that *by default* and without adding an uncommon character as the second argument, `PARSENAME()` *acts like* the inverse of `QUOTENAME()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In a similar _spirit_ that is why my comment was that I didn't believe that PARSENAME was the reverse of QUOTENAME, and that I didn't think that the original question was about putting brackets around strings and removing them again. I understood the question to be "How does Microsoft parse Object Names..." (_which is answered by PaulWhite_) and in the end proving ypercube's thesis to be wrong. According to the documentation `'`(single quotes), `"` (double quotes) and `[ ]`(square brackets) are valid quotation marks for the function `QUOTENAME`. I'll add more examples.

Comment: My point is not that single quotes aren't valid arguments to `QUOTENAME()`. It's that we don't use them in SQL Server to quote identifiers, and the question was clearly in the context of parsing identifiers.

Comment: Could we mutually agree that `PARSENAME()` is the opposite of `QUOTENAME()` **IF** `QUOTENAME()` is limited to `"` (double quotes) and `[ ]` (square brackets) **AND** the parameter `object_piece` for the `PARSENAME()` function is limited to `1`?

Comment: Sure, I don't think anyone was trying to assert that they were inverse functions *in all possible contrived scenarios*.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion: `PARSENAME(x , 1)` is the inverse of `QUOTENAME(x, q)` when `q` is not the single quote ;)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the clarification. I'll add it to my answer.